# Updating coordinates of vertex in polyline using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geometry

I want to update the point coordinates which are not correct on polyline. I tried many times to update it using python, but my script didn't work. The first attribute table is the station_id and its correct coordinates that need to update in polyline.

[image]

The second is the polyline's attribute table.

[image]

For example, the from_id "18 " in polyline is not correct, it need to be update to correct coordinates according to table 1.

How to find these wrong station_id (in From_id or To_id field) and replace it according to table 1 using ArcPy?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
import arcpy

points = r'C:\path_to_your\points.shp'
lines = r'C:\path_to_your\points.shp'
point_id_field = 'Your_ID_Field'

# grab point geometry and ID
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, [point_id_field, 'SHAPE@']) as rows:
    pd = dict(r for r in rows)

# now update the line geometry based on From and To Id's
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lines, ['From_id', 'To_id', 'SHAPE@']) as rows:
    for r in rows:
        if r[0] in pd and r[1] in pd:
            for part in r[2]:
                part.replace(0, pd[r[0]].centroid) # need to use centroid because it is an arcpy.Point object
                part.replace(part.count -1, pd[r[1]].centroid)
                r[2] = arcpy.Polyline(part)
            rows.updateRow(r)
```

One disclaimer, this is designed to work on single part geometries.  If you have multi part line features you'll have to figure out how to map the start/end points of each part.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would use arcpy.da.[UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

> UpdateCursor establishes read-write access to records returned from a
>   feature class or table.
>
> Returns an iterator of lists. The order of values in the list matches
>   the order of fields specified by the field_names argument.

You can access a geometry object for the feature using the SHAPE@ token.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many times, i wrote this script. It finally solved my problems which i just want to correct the wrong vertex and remain the right ones. Only the wrong vertex coordinates in point table.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "E:\\test"

points = "point.shp"
lines = "merge_line.shp"
point_id_field = 'station_id'

points_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, [point_id_field, 'SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y'])
points_dict={}
for points_row in points_cursor:
    station_id = points_row[0]
    x = points_row[1]
    y = points_row[2]
    points_dict[str(int(station_id))] = str(x),str(y)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lines,["From_id","To_id","OID@","SHAPE@"]) as update_cursor:
    for update_row in update_cursor:
        print("Feature{0}:".format(update_row[2]))
        from_id = update_row[0]
        to_id = update_row[1]
        if from_id in points_dict.keys() and to_id not in points_dict.keys():
            print from_id
            geometry = update_row[3]
            pts = geometry.getPart(0)
            n = len(pts)
            pt_array1 = arcpy.Array()
            for i in xrange(n):
                if i == 0:
                    frompoint1 = pts.getObject(i)
                    print frompoint1.X, frompoint1.Y
                    frompoint1.X = points_dict[from_id][0]
                    frompoint1.Y = points_dict[from_id][1]
                    print frompoint1.X ,frompoint1.Y
                    pt_array1.add(frompoint1)

                elif i == 1:
                    topoint1 = pts.getObject(i)
                    print topoint1.X,topoint1.Y
                    pt_array1.add(topoint1)
            new_polyline_geometry = arcpy.Polyline(pt_array1)        
            update_row[3] = new_polyline_geometry
            update_cursor.updateRow(update_row)        
        elif from_id in points_dict.keys() and to_id in points_dict.keys():
            print from_id, to_id
            geometry = update_row[3]
            pts = geometry.getPart(0)
            n = len(pts)
            pt_array2 = arcpy.Array()
            for i in xrange(n):
                if i == 0:
                    frompoint2 = pts.getObject(i)
                    print frompoint2.X, frompoint2.Y
                    frompoint2.X = points_dict[from_id][0]
                    frompoint2.Y = points_dict[from_id][1]
                    print frompoint2.X ,frompoint2.Y
                    pt_array2.add(frompoint2)
                elif i == 1:
                    topoint2 = pts.getObject(i)
                    print topoint2.X, topoint2.Y
                    topoint2.X = points_dict[to_id][0]
                    topoint2.Y = points_dict[to_id][1]
                    print topoint2.X, topoint2.Y
                    pt_array2.add(topoint2)
            new_polyline_geometry = arcpy.Polyline(pt_array2)        
            update_row[3] = new_polyline_geometry
            update_cursor.updateRow(update_row)
        elif to_id in points_dict.keys() and from_id not in points_dict.keys():
            print to_id
            geometry = update_row[3]
            pts = geometry.getPart(0)
            n = len(pts)
            pt_array3 = arcpy.Array()
            for i in xrange(n):
                if i == 0:
                    frompoint3 = pts.getObject(i)
                    print frompoint3.X,frompoint3.Y
                    pt_array3.add(frompoint3)
                if i == 1:
                    topoint3 = pts.getObject(i)
                    print topoint3.X, topoint3.Y
                    topoint3.X = points_dict[to_id][0]
                    topoint3.Y = points_dict[to_id][1]
                    print topoint3.X, topoint3.Y
                    pt_array3.add(topoint3)
            new_polyline_geometry = arcpy.Polyline(pt_array3)        
            update_row[3] = new_polyline_geometry
            update_cursor.updateRow(update_row)
```